# Подкиньте идей для практики

Tags: php

Изучаю PHP, чтение теории утомляет, а писать тривиальный блог не хочется, подкиньте не особо трудных идей для практики языка.

Answer (score 1):

Форум свой напиши или любой другой не маленький сайт попутно изучая php и переписывая код по мере изучения чего-то нового и эффективного

Answer (score 1):

возьми API вконтакте и попробуй сделать приложение для vk.com

Answer (score 1):

Скоро олимпиада :) поэтому одна из стандартных задач - написать оболочку для ведения учета медалей со всевозможными фильтрами сортировками, можно придумать свои коэфициенты. И сделать так, чтобы было красиво ) Еще можно добавить тотализатор на очки (ставить на спортсменов, страну)

Answer (score 0):

Весь мир Internet перед вами. Вот я лично предлагаю всегда всем вопрошающим написать очень простой *сайт* знакомств (без CSS  и прочего). Регистрация, вход, свой аккаунт, добавление себе фоток и обмен сообщениями. PHP синтаксис, сессии, немного advanced, базы данных - вот и практика. Не пожалеете.

Comment: Сайт без CSS -- это сильно.) Может, без CMS?

Comment: Да, именно. Потому что в большинстве случаев изучающий начинает "зависать" на элементах дизайна, порой уделяя часы на "а может быть этот колор?", теряя из виду сам функционал северного сценария.
Движок без CSS, описанный мной, прекрасно подходит для практики освоения PHP.

Comment: Эмм, я вообще себе не представляю сайт, который будет читабилен без задания через CSS хотя бы позиции элементов, отступов и обтекания. Без иконочек, эффектов и прочего можно и нужно обойтись, на этапе написания кода, согласен.